# lsof showing duplicates entry of files opened by elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, devops, centos7, file-descriptor, lsof

on lsof I can see there are multiple entries of the same files opened by elastic search.
The files are in format of `elasticdb/data/nodes/0/indices/AW0VfnbAQB-7Z43UAXCUdw/0/index/_1.cfs`

The interesting thing is on counting the duplicate occurrence I found that all files are showing the same number. Each file is repeated by 189 times in lsof's output.

Also `lsof` showing millions of files are opened by elastic search.

How to resolve this ?

Following commands I have used

```sh
$ lsof > out.log
$ grep '/flowtracker/lindb/elasticdb/data/nodes' out.log |awk -F '/flowtracker/lindb/elasticdb/data/nodes' '{print $2'}|sort|uniq -c 
    189 /0/indices/F6k-A5LGSYuoIqmW586Q_g/0/index/_b.fdx                                                                                                                                                
    189 /0/indices/F6k-A5LGSYuoIqmW586Q_g/0/index/_b_Lucene80_0.dvd                                                                                                                                                
    189 /0/indices/F6k-A5LGSYuoIqmW586Q_g/0/index/_b_Lucene84_0.doc                                                                                                                                                
    189 /0/indices/F6k-A5LGSYuoIqmW586Q_g/0/index/_b_Lucene84_0.pos                                                                                                                                                
    189 /0/indices/F6k-A5LGSYuoIqmW586Q_g/0/index/_b_Lucene84_0.tim                                                                                                                                                
    189 /0/indices/F6k-A5LGSYuoIqmW586Q_g/0/index/_b_Lucene84_0.tip                                                                                                                                                
    189 /0/indices/F6k-A5LGSYuoIqmW586Q_g/0/index/_b.nvd                                                                                                                                                           
    189 /0/indices/F6k-A5LGSYuoIqmW586Q_g/0/index/write.lock          
    

$ lsof | awk '{ print $2; }' | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
    1401246 55487                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        600 26551                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        464 19420                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        440 41120                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        432 44979                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        420 159914                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        420 15619                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        384 50748                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        356 69279                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        356 48357  
$ lsof -p 55487|wc -l
7403 
$ lsof -u $USER|wc -l
7572
$ ulimit -n
66535    enter code here
```

Comment: Can you show which command you're running?

Comment: Updated the question with commands, tell me if you are looking for something else